# How to use NodeJS to combat social sharing and search engines issues when using single-page frameworks like AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, optimization, seo

I read an [article](http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/171/enable-rich-social-sharing-in-your-angularjs-app) about social sharing issues in AngularJS and how to combat by using Apache as a proxy.

The solution is usable for small websites. But if a web app has 20+ different pages, I have to url-write and create static files for all of them. Moreover, a different stack is added to the app by using PHP and Apache.

1. Can we use NodeJS as the proxy and re-write the url, and what's the approach?
2. Is there a way to minimize static files creation?
3. Is there a way to remove proxy, url-rewrite, and static files all together? For example, inside our NodeJS app to check the user agent, if it is facebook bot or twitter and the like, we use request module to download our page and return the raw html code for them, is it a plausible solution?

Answer (score 4):

Normally when someone shares a url in a social network, that social network request that page to generate a preview/thumbnail (aka "scrape").
Most likely those scrapers won't run javascript, so they need a static html version of that page.
Same applies for search engines (even though Google and others are starting to support javascript sites).

Here's a good approach for an SPA to still support scrapers:

- use history.pushState in angular to get virtual urls when navigating thru your app (ie. urls without a `#`)
- server-side (node.js or any), detect if a request comes from a user or a bot (eg. check the User-Agent using this lib https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-bot )
- if the request url has a file extension, it's probably a static resource request (images, .css, .js), proxy to get the static file
- if the request url is a page, for real users, if the url is a page (ie. not a static resource) always serve your index.html that loads your angular app (pro tip: keep this file cached in memory)
- if the request url is a page, serve a pre-rendered version of the requested url (they won't run javascript), this is the hard part (side note: ReactJS makes this problem much simpler), you can use a service like https://prerender.io/ they'd take care of loading your angular app, and saving each page as html (if you're curious, they use a headless/virtual browser in memory called PhantomJS to do that, simulating what a real user would do clicking "Save As..."), then you can request and proxy those prerendered pages to bot requests (like social network scrappers). If you want, it's possible to run a prerender instance on your own servers.

All this server-side process I described is implemented in this express.js middleware by prerender:
https://github.com/prerender/prerender-node/blob/master/index.js
(even if you don't like prerender, you can use that code as implementation guide)

Alternatively, here's an implementation example using only nginx:
https://gist.github.com/thoop/8165802